# Jmeter will not login to Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, cookies, jmeter, performance-testing

I am currently doing a performance test on Wordpress as part of my PhD research. I am using Jmeter for this.

I did a test record of login into my local installed Wordpress site and later ran the test. It does give an error saying cookies are blocked or not supported by browser.

I have changed jmeter properties setting of cookies as follows: `CookieManager.check.cookies=false` and `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` but it still doesn’t work.

Comment: Did you add HTTP Cookie Manager? Please share View Results Tree screenshot of the login request. From my experience, cookies are set at sub-domain level also, which we need to send. Above settings help you in saving dub-domain cookies and sent them. not sure what the problem is. Did you restart JMeter after that?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried running the experiment tonight so that i could post the error screen to you all, but to my amazement, it worked. although it failed twice, I don't know why, but I am glad it now works.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan in order to tell JMeter to track and automatically handle cookies.

Also consider following other steps from the [How To Make JMeter Behave More Like A Real Browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) guide to wit:

- Add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to represent browser headers
- Add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to work as a browser cache
- Configure your HTTP Request samplers to:

  - download embedded resources (scripts, styles, images)
  - use a concurrent thread pool for this
  - download resources only for your application under test domain(s)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did add all these things, But something I noticed is that the httpcookie manager does not record anything. Meanwhile, when I used Blazemeter, it did record many cookie value. I tried running the experiment tonight, so that I could post the error to you all, but to my amazement, it started working.